# Save a template of a section in elementor with different text and image depending on the site

Tags: wordpress, templates, vue-component, web-component, elementor

I have to create a website with wordpress and all the sites have the same design under the header where there is an Image and then text under it.

Now if I were to just create a template of the section in elementor, I could copy that same section everywhere and then change the img and text but if I would like to do changes to the template in the future (eg. different height of image or margin etc.). It would not change all the occurences where I pasted that template and as such I would have to change every site I have manually.

I am familiar with vuejs and there you have the posibility to create components to which you can pass variables for some text or image the component uses but if you change some styling in the component every occurence of this component changes aswell.

Is there something similar to this in wordpress, where I can create a "component" which has placeholders in them for text and the img link and I can then pass a different value to every site where i use this component?

Comment: Wordpress and vue js are two different things, if you want to reuse something you would create once, it can be achieved in a number of ways, there are shortcodes, plugins, themes, and more in wordpress. Please when puting a question on stack overlow, know exactly where are you stuck and ask to the point question.

Answer (score -1):

By the sounds of what you're saying you want to be working with the 'Theme Builder' in Elementor (assuming this is what you're using?) and dynamically populate your pages.

So, you'd create a template inside of theme builder - and dynamically fill the content using maybe ACF or JetEngine.

I hope this gets you a little closer to what you're trying to do. If you haven't used ACF or JetEngine - Check them out... Amazing.

Also too... in Elementor check out Global Widgets... this may help a little too.

Best of luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).